# Does django rest framework query all objects from database for a single instance?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

When working with RetrieveAPIView *queryset* must be defined and usually it is defined as queryset = `<Model>`.objects.all()

Why does retrieving a single instance require loading all the objects?

Comment: You don't load all the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't load all the objects. The queryset is *not* evaluated. The [**`RetrieveAPIView`** <sup>[classy-drf]</sup>](https://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.generics/RetrieveAPIView.html) will use the queryset as a base to make queries. Indeed, in the `.retrieve(…)` method, it will obtain the object:

> ```
> def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>     instance = self.get_object()
>     serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
>     return Response(serializer.data)
> ```

and the `.get_object(…)` method, it will fetch the single object:

> ```
> def get_object(self):
>     """
>     Returns the object the view is displaying.
>
>     You may want to override this if you need to provide non-standard
>     queryset lookups.  Eg if objects are referenced using multiple
>     keyword arguments in the url conf.
>     """
>     queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
>     # Perform the lookup filtering.
>     lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
>
>     assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
>         'Expected view %s to be called with a URL keyword argument '
>         'named "%s". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` '
>         'attribute on the view correctly.' %
>         (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
>     )
>
>     filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
>     obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
>
>     # May raise a permission denied
>     self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
>
>     return obj
> ```

It will thus for example boil down to `get_object_or_404(MyModel.objects.all(), pk=42)`, and this will make a query to fetch the single record with primary key `42`. `QuerySet`s are lazy: the `MyModel.objects.all()` is *not* evaluated unless the queryset is consumed, but here it thus is used to construct a new queryset that will eventually fetch a single record.